# In Kotlin Multiplatorm after renaming packages can't access the MR resource folder

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to get a json file from the MR/files folder but I get a NullPointerException.

My MR folder structure:

[image]

My class for accessing resources

```
expect class ResourceReader() {
    fun readResource(name: String): String
}
```

```
actual class ResourceReader {
    actual fun readResource(name: String): String = 
        javaClass.classLoader!!.getResourceAsStream(name).use { stream ->
            InputStreamReader(stream).use { reader ->
                reader.readText()
            }
    }
}
```

The code where this method is called

```
val jsonString = ResourceReader().readResource("MR/files/locations.json")
```

My library dependencies for multiplatform resources

```
plugins {
    ...
    id("dev.icerock.mobile.multiplatform-resources")
    ...
}
```

```
sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                ...
                api("dev.icerock.moko:resources:0.21.1")
                ...
            }

        }
...
```

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath("dev.icerock.moko:resources-generator:0.17.0")
        ...
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven(url = "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/")
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the target platforms? You class for accessing resources can be only used with JVM target platforms (so there is no need to use kotlin-multiplatform). Also it seems you are trying to use Moko-resources library, then follow [the official guide](https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-resources#example-10---plain-file-resource-access)

Comment: For now, only for Android.

Comment: then do not use moko-resources and kotlin-multiplatform, use regular android library without common main source set and everything will work fine